# Why do QUIC packets require a sequence number?

Tags: transport-protocol

This may be a silly question, but if in QUIC we maintain separate sliding windows for each stream, why is there a need for sequencing even below the stream level?

It seems to me that an application will not receive the same data twice because we already sequence streams by themselves, and we also can acknowledge each stream separately without sequencing the packets themselves.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Comment: dear @RonMaupin, according to Google (the authors), IETF working group (e.g., [rfc900](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9000.html#)) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC), QUIC is a transport protocol, aka on layer 4 not above it. Using UDP encapsulation does not automatically make a protocol above UDP layer.

Comment: QUIC uses UDP as the transport protocol. NAPT must also translate the transport protocol address, but it knows nothing about QUIC because it is above the transport protocol. NAPT can only translate TCP and UDP transport protocols. ICMP is an integral part of IP, so NAPT translates ICMP as part of the network protocol.

Comment: @RonMaupin IMHO, QUIC is a transport-layer protocol. It just rides on top of UDP due to the ubiquity of NAPT. Whether a protocol is translated by NAPT or where it is implemented isn't relevant.

Comment: @RonMaupin read the RFC - the first line "This document defines the core of the QUIC **transport protocol.** "

Comment: on the other hand, capability of NAT processing is not a requirement for being at or above OSI layer 4.

Comment: @RonMaupin VXLAN uses UDP encapsulation and PTPP uses TCP, are they both off-topic also? EAP-TLS uses a TLS tunnel, which is technically application layer, is that also off-topic? It seems to me that a transport protocol remains on topic, even if it uses encapsulation over another transport layer

Comment: @Charlieface, you are referring to protocols configured on on-topic network devices, not off-topic hosts/servers for applications. For example, DNS is an application-layer protocol, and the configuration and use of it for hosts/servers is off-topic here, but the configuration in on-topic devices like the built-in DNS server in a router is on-topic here. In any case, there have been no reopen votes.